# How do I "undo" my mobile chat preference?

Tags: support, chat, chat-profile

Although I am given notice that I can change this option in my profile preferences, I can't, for the life of me, figure how that is done, exactly.  Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 3):

On your chat profile there is a tab for `prefs`- on the bottom of that page is the checkbox for **New Mobile UI (beta)**.

[image]

It doesn't appear there is a link to your user profile in the menu of either the new UI or the legacy UI when in a chat room, but one can tap on your username if you have a recent message or else tap the `people` button from the `menu` button at the bottom (of the legacy UI) and then tap on your username to access your profile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sam, for your very detailed answer.  I greatly appreciate the time and effort you put into this to help me!

Comment: @Jack great - if you haven’t already, please consider [voting and/or accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)